# DebounceTime Rxjs when same parameters being passed in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have multiple components using this service and I want to debounceTime when I'm piping in the same value but if it's a different value, let it through. In this code, I want to somehow check if a types been used before

```js
from(types).pipe(
  debounceTime(1000), 
   map(([data, type]) => {
  // mapping logic 
  }),
)
```

It very similar to this issue https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2403 and I'm trying to understand it but I'm hoping to used RXJS code still

Thanks

Comment: So, if `a` is emitted, then you start a `debounceTime`, and if `a` is emitted again, then `debounceTime` will do its job, but if `b` is emitted, then the current `debounceTime` should be destroyed, right? This means that if after the previous `b` comes `a`, it will be let through, right?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to use the `pairwise` operator to emit both the previous and current values, then use the `debounce` operator to compare the values and debounce accordingly:

```js
from(types).pipe(
  pairwise(),
  debounce(([prev, cur]) => (prev === cur)
    ? timer(1000)
    : EMPTY
  ),
  map(([, cur]) => cur), // No further need for prev value
  map(([data, type]) => {
    // mapping logic 
  }),
)
```